# C# Generic method for getting field names based on attributes

Tags: c#, api, reflection

I am trying to make a generic method to be used in a lot of places in my code
I can make it work with the following code:

```
public static void GetFieldNames(System.Object obj, List<string> list)
{
    // Getting the class
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    // Getting all the fields(Variables)
    FieldInfo[] fis = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    for (int i = 0; i < fis.Length; i++) 
    {
        // Filtering through the list and if the field(Variable) is marked with a ShowInToolTip attribute ....
        ShowInToolTip attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fis[i], typeof(ShowInToolTip)) as ShowInToolTip;
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            list.Add(fis[i].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have to specify which attribute I want the list to add in the method,
meaning I have to create a new method every time I want to find different attribute to add.

So I am trying to have the attribute added to the method as a generic Type parameter
I have the code below:

```
public static void GetFieldNames<Att>(System.Object obj, List<string> list) where Att : System.Attribute
{
    // Getting the class
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    // Getting all the fields(Variables)
    FieldInfo[] fis = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    for (int i = 0; i < fis.Length; i++) 
    {
        // Filtering through the list and if the field(Variable) is marked with a ShowInToolTip attribute ....
        Att attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fis[i], typeof(Att)) as Att;
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            list.Add(fis[i].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

and I am implementing as follows:

```
List<string> stats = new List<string>();
CharacterStats characterStats;
GetFieldNames<Stat>(characterStats, stats);
```

But unfortunately I am getting a null reference error.
It is quite late while typing this so I am sure I am making a simple error but if anyone could help just look over the code that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Declared variable `characterStats` isn't initialized. Obviously you'll get NRE in the first line, `obj.GetType()`.

Comment: @Dennis It will actually be a compile-time error: use of unassigned local variable.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: you're right. Probably, OP didn't post actual code.

Comment: Should this method work without a `CharacterStats` instance? Maybe you want something like `GetFieldNames<TObject, TAtt>`?

Comment: Getting properties like this is pretty unusual, and quite slow, especially in a gaming environment. Without knowing your actual use case, it seems like an interface would be a better option than reflection.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, probably should've mentioned it is in Unity. I am creating the player with all its children in a menu item [MenuItem("GameObject/3D Object/Player")] which runs before any initializing methods Unity provides and it does not like having MonoBahaviour initialized outside of these.

Comment: Thanks @JohnathanBarclay but if I try and use reference type parameter I get an error that I am using the variable like a type.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG this is the first time I'm making a game and I am wanting a method that gets all the fields I have specified in the the stats class with attributes and create a game object for each of those stats, so this will only be called once upon creation which should not affect the speed of the game. This is for the inventory which I am wanting to show the stats of the player.

Comment: Then why not store that data in a JSON file or a static Dictionary for example?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired outcome by rearranging the method a bit,
By removing the object as a parameter and putting in a system type parameter in instead bypassing the need to Type t = obj.GetType();

```
public static void GetFieldNames<Att>(System.Type t, List<string> list) where Att : System.Attribute
{
    // Getting all the fields(Variables)
    FieldInfo[] fis = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    for (int i = 0; i < fis.Length; i++) 
    {
        // Filtering through the list and if the field(Variable) is marked with a Stat attribute ....
        Att attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fis[i], typeof(Att)) as Att;
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            list.Add(fis[i].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

and then I call it with:

```
List<string> stats = new List<string>();
GetFieldNames<Stat>(typeof(CharacterStats), stats);
```